# Local (?) variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
test1 = 0
def test_func():
    test1 += 1
test_func()
```

I am receiving the following error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'test1' referenced before assignment.

Error says that `'test1'` is local variable but i thought that this variable is global

So is it global or local and how to solve this error without passing global `test1` as argument to `test_func`?

Comment: It is local, because you assign to it within the function.

Comment: I received the same error but in my case it turned out to be an indentation problem. The code I was modifying was indented with spaces, but my editor was indenting with tabs. Dumb mistake on my part, and not at all the problem you had, but I hope to save someone out there some time by commenting here -- this was the first hit in my Google search.

Answer (score 284, accepted):

In order for you to modify `test1` while inside a function you will need to do define `test1` as a global variable, for example:

```
test1 = 0
def test_func():
    global test1 
    test1 += 1
test_func()
```

However, if you only need to read the global variable you can print it without using the keyword `global`, like so:

```
test1 = 0
def test_func():
    print(test1)
test_func()
```

But whenever you need to modify a global variable you must use the keyword `global`.

Comment: Wow, this is such an *ahem* *ahem* odd language design decision.

Answer (score 64):

Best solution: Don't use `global`s

```
>>> test1 = 0
>>> def test_func(x):
        return x + 1

>>> test1 = test_func(test1)
>>> test1
1
```

Comment: Totally agree, you don't know how global can mess up with the code later :)

Comment: so you dont modify it inside of function but create new temp variable ?

Answer (score 12):

You have to specify that test1 is global:

```py
test1 = 0
def test_func():
    global test1
    test1 += 1
test_func()
```