# Python local variable 'Current_Balance' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Idon't know why this is happening. Been trying to fix for sometime now

```
def Bettings():
    while True:
        if "Rolling in 35." in Label.text:
            Updated_Balance = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="balance"]""")
        if "Rolling in 23." in Label.text:
            Current_Balance = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="balance"]""")

        if "Rolling in 28." in Label.text:

            if Current_Balance < Updated_Balance:

                GrayBetButton.click()
            if Current_Balance > Updated_Balance:
                RedBetButton.click()

Bettings()
```

Error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Current_Balance' referenced before assignm
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local (?) variable referenced before assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904981/local-variable-referenced-before-assignment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define your variable `Current_Balance` only when you go through the `"Rolling in 23." in Label.text` 'path'.

When you go directly through the `"Rolling in 28." in Label.text` path, this variable has not been created yet.

You might want to create this variable at the top, like this:

```
def Bettings():
    current_balance = 0
    while True:
        if "Rolling in 35." in Label.text:
            updated_balance = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="balance"]""")
        if "Rolling in 23." in Label.text:
            current_balance = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="balance"]""")
        if "Rolling in 28." in Label.text:
            if current_balance < updated_balance:
                grayBetButton.click()
            if current_Balance > updated_balance:
                redBetButton.click()

Bettings()
```

Note that by convention, variable names tend to start with a non capitalized letter (capitalization is preferred for class names).