# Local Variable Referenced Before Assignment.. Sometimes

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, local-variables

I know this has been asked before because I've searched around for an answer but the questions that I've read through don't really address my problem. I wrote a river warning system using Python3. Initially the script would only retrieve the data for the river closest to my house, so I decided to do a re-write or version upgrade, I suppose, so that any river could be used. Everything has been working pretty nice until I entered the Mississippi river URL and then I started getting

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'action' referenced before
>   assignment.

Here is the code:

**EDIT** - Added the entire function to show where `ALERT_LEVELS` is defined

```
def check_river(url):
ALERT_LEVELS = ["major", "moderate", "flood", "action", "low"]
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0"}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BS(response.text, 'lxml')

data = []

 #process the data returned from waterdata.usgs.gov
for river in soup.select("h1.data_name"):

    river_name = river.get_text(strip=True)
    river_data = river.find_next_sibling("div")
    data.append({
        "name": river_name,
        "stage": river_data.select_one(".stage_stage_flow").get_text(strip=True).replace("Latest Stage: ", ""),
        "flood_lvl": river_data.select_one(".flood_stage_flow").get_text(strip=True).replace("Flood Stage: ", "").replace(" Feet", ""),
        "warns": river_data.select_one(".current_warns_statmnts_ads > b").next_sibling.strip(),
        "alerts": {
        alert_name: alert_value.get_text(strip=True)
        for alert_name, alert_value in
     zip(ALERT_LEVELS, river_data.select(".flood_his_lwr .box_square table tr > td:nth-of-type(2)"))
    }
})

 #define river data per station and set conditionals
try:
    for n in range(len(data)):
        station = data[n]['name']

        if data[n]['stage'] == 'n/a' or data[n]['stage'] == 'Latest Flow: n/a' or data[n]['stage'] == 'Latest Stage: n/a':
            if len(data[n]['alerts']) < 5:
                pass
        else:
            stage = float(data[n]['stage'])
            for a in ALERT_LEVELS:
                if a in data[n]['alerts']:
                    action = float(data[n]['alerts']['action'])
                    flood = float(data[n]['alerts']['flood'])
                    moderate = float(data[n]['alerts']['moderate'])
                    major = float(data[n]['alerts']['major'])

                    if major == 0:
                        major = action
                    elif moderate == 0:
                        moderate = action
                    elif flood == 0:
                        flood == action   
                    elif action == 0 and flood != 0:
                        action = flood  
                else:
                    pass                    

            if stage < action:
                pass
            elif stage > major and major != 0:
                print('{} stage ({}) is above [Major FLood Stage: {}]'.format(station, stage, major))
            elif stage > moderate and moderate != 0:
                print('{} stage ({}) is above [Moderate FLood Stage: {}]'.format(station, stage, moderate))
            elif stage > flood and flood != 0:
                print('{} stage ({}) is above [FLood Stage: {}]'.format(station, stage, flood))
            elif stage > action and action != 0:
                print('{} stage ({}) is above [Action Stage: {}]'.format(station, stage, action))
except KeyError:
    raise
```

so then when I execute the function `get_river()` here are the results:

```
>>> from riverwarn import get_river
>>> mississippi = 'http://water.weather.gov/ahps2/river.php?wfo=jan&wfoid=18743&riverid=203833&pt%5B%5D=all&allpoints=143846%2C142736%2C143816%2C143998%2C145144%2C142659%2C145887%2C144081%2C142375%2C143866%2C141506%2C142962%2C143885%2C153060%2C143323%2C144201%2C144542%2C142873%2C143260%2C143099%2C142560%2C144186%2C143177%2C142054%2C143945%2C144055%2C141370%2C143630%2C141931%2C142812%2C141676%2C142534%2C144568%2C143535%2C144589%2C143030%2C144031%2C143079%2C144282%2C141445%2C141722%2C141383%2C143445%2C143646%2C152882%2C143787%2C143574%2C143545%2C142773%2C141629%2C144517%2C142500%2C143196%2C142105%2C142509%2C142418%2C152996%2C152997%2C152998%2C144108%2C141463%2C152999%2C153000%2C153001%2C153002%2C152909%2C141839%2C143934%2C141618%2C146423%2C143366%2C147048%2C142172%2C151794%2C153107%2C141493%2C142940%2C144619%2C144798%2C151521%2C151430%2C144609%2C151338%2C141308%2C151468%2C144449%2C143828%2C151447%2C151342%2C142711%2C151473%2C151474%2C151475%2C151469%2C151476%2C151477%2C151448%2C151450%2C151455%2C151478%2C151451%2C151479%2C151480%2C151452&data%5B%5D=xml'
>>> sabine = 'http://water.weather.gov/ahps2/river.php?wfo=SHV&wfoid=18715&riverid=203413&pt%5B%5D=all&allpoints=143204%2C147710%2C141425%2C144668%2C141750%2C141658%2C141942%2C143491%2C144810%2C143165%2C145368&data%5B%5D=xml'
>>> redriver = 'http://water.weather.gov/ahps2/river.php?wfo=shv&wfoid=18715&riverid=204727&pt%5B%5D=all&allpoints=146209%2C142575%2C141732%2C141489%2C146261%2C146208%2C142772%2C142879%2C141588%2C142687%2C141313%2C144336%2C143593%2C141633%2C141650%2C143326%2C142421%2C143017%2C142886%2C143393%2C142504%2C141575%2C144273%2C142926%2C142145%2C144020%2C147033%2C142204%2C143687%2C142816%2C143243%2C144337%2C142619%2C142061%2C142956%2C152444%2C152443&data%5B%5D=xml'
>>> riogrande = 'http://water.weather.gov/ahps2/river.php?wfo=crp&wfoid=18767&riverid=204592&pt%5B%5D=all&allpoints=144166%2C144467%2C143214%2C143547%2C142661%2C143437%2C151195%2C144782%2C142474%2C141927%2C143988%2C144335%2C151375%2C151376%2C151377%2C141895%2C151378%2C141579%2C141562%2C151365%2C144387%2C151379%2C144104%2C151438%2C151443%2C151444%2C144623%2C141482%2C141924%2C143303%2C148129%2C145933%2C142442%2C144066%2C141780%2C144293%2C146608%2C144871%2C144021%2C144722%2C141667%2C144458%2C143692%2C145293%2C142278%2C143836%2C141362%2C141311%2C142508%2C141834&data%5B%5D=xml'
>>> get_river(sabine)
Sabine River At Deweyville (DWYT2) stage (24.12) is above [FLood Stage: 24.0]
>>> get_river(riogrande)
>>> get_river(redriver)
Red River At Lake Texoma near Denison (DSNT2) stage (619.29) is above [Major FLood Stage: 34.0]
Red River Above Red River Lock 2 (RRBL1) stage (64.42) is above [Major FLood Stage: 40.0]
>>> get_river(mississippi)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/skywalker/scripts/python/riverwarn/riverwarn.py", line 73, in get_river
    if stage < action:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'action' referenced before assignment
```

I've moved the variables around the appropriate `if` and `for` blocks but that doesn't seem to help. I've tried assigning them as `global` variables as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904981/local-variable-referenced-before-assignment). I've also gone back over the URL data from water.weather.gov and compared each river stage/flood alerts and it all appears to be the same for each river. So now I'm just confused as to why the variable 'action' is referenced *before* assignment in the Mississippi river data when it's not in the first three.

Comment: How's ALERT_LEVELS defined? It seems your code may reach the following condition: `if stage < action` with action undefined

Comment: updated the OP with the complete code to show where `ALERT_LEVELS` is defined. sorry about that, I forgot it had been defined earlier in the html parsing portion

Answer (score 3):

Just from looking at the code, the reason might be:

`ALERT_LEVELS` is empty, so `for a in ALERT_LEVELS` doesn't run

or

none of the objects in `ALERT_LEVELS` matches in `data[n]['alerts']`, so `if a in data[n]['alerts']` never triggered

A workaround to this is set `action = None` before the for loop and check whether `action is None` afterwards to handle this situation.

Cool App btw :)

Comment: Thanks! It actually started out as a way to see if the river near my house was full enough for fishing. Then I figured I could use it to check for flood stages and issue an alert. `ALERT_LEVELS` was defined earlier in the html parsing part of the script. I forgot about that so I edited the OP to show where and how it's defined.

Comment: I added `action = None` as you suggested and now it is throwing errors when doing the stage comparisons: `TypeError: unorderable types: float() < NoneType()` so I'm going to have to work that out but it's a start anyway. Thanks again!

Comment: You can add another if statement to deal with the situation when action is None, something like `if action is None: do sth; elif stage < action pass ......` or you can add in the bottom another `except` statement receiving TypeError like `except TypeError: #do something`. I will prefer the first one tho.

Comment: So those NoneTypes were a real pain, but I was able to get the app working once I accounted for them all. I posted the full script at CodeReview rather than re-post and clutter up this thread. Here's the link if you're interested: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/165485/river-flood-warning-system-v2-1-those-pesky-nonetypes